# Trimming sorted set by score

Tags: redis, redis-py

In a Django app, I use redis to maintain a global sorted set where user ids are stored with the score of current time since epoch.

After every 11 minutes, I am to run an asynchronous task that trims the sorted set to solely values that were saved in the previous 10 minutes, *nothing beyond*.

Would the following accomplish this? I'm unsure about edge cases (e.g. will this ensure all old values are deleted or will some leak, etc.):

```
time_now = time.time() #current time since epoch
ten_mins_ago = time_now - (10*60)
eleven_mins_ago = time_now - (11*60)
my_redis_server.zremrangebyscore(sorted_set,eleven_mins_ago,ten_mins_ago)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `eleven_mins_ago` with the string value `-inf` to delete everything that's older than 10 minutes and to avoid any "leak"age. Refer to the [*Exclusive intervals and infinity*](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore#exclusive-intervals-and-infinity) section of the `ZRANGE`'s documentation page for full details and explanation.